# How to run a kaa file on Windows?

Tags: kaa

I generated sdk in C ++ by sandbox.

I created the app using the steps described on this page, "http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Your-first-Kaa-application/".

On Ubuntu I run the kaa-app file with the "./kaa-app" command on the terminal.

**Question**

How can I run this file on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to compile the whole project on windows - with the windows compiler to be more specific.
Than you will get a windows executable (.exe).